# Unknown UL LI tag broke the layout

Tags: magento2, layout, html

I got this annoying issue:

[image]

that's unwanted spaces thats caused by unknown HTML:

[image]

[image]

My question is how to remove that unwanted annoying html (UL/LI) from home page?

Thanks

Comment: You can manage it from here: /var/www/html/magento226/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/Magento_Catalog/layout/default.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually remove it using **CSS rule** **`display:none`** of display property in your **custom CSS:**

```
ul.compare{
  display:none;
}
```

Comment: can I use something like <referenceBlock name="name.here" remove="true"/>?

Comment: yah that should work as well, but do it with caution as other element in that block will also be removed.

Comment: I am prefer to remove it using <referenceBlock name="name.here" remove="true"/>, but I don't know the name of this element?